# replace . with , in a string

Tags: php, string, replace

I've been trying to use preg_replace to replace **period** within my string to **comma**.

For example,

```
<?php
$string = "Hey you.";
$new_string = preg_replace("/./", ",", $new_string);
echo $new_string;
?>
```

I do have an error in here in which I am aware, because I am quite confused with patterns. Any insights? Thanks.

Comment: There is [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) for a reason ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `str_replace`

```
$new_string = str_replace(".", ",", $new_string);
```

The problem with your regex is that you haven't escaped the `.`, and `.` is matching any character.

You can do this

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/\./", ",", $new_string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and answer. Learned something new.

Comment: I am waiting for the accept countdown. I'll accept this as soon as the timer lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

I read awhile ago that `strtr` is faster than `str_replace`. This may or may not still be true:

```
$new_string = strtr($new_string, '.', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php
$string = "Hey you.";
$new_string = preg_replace('/\./', ',', $new_string);
echo $new_string;
?>
```